# How to initialize a list of lists of different sizes with all zeros

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have a list of lists of different lengths. For example, `A` is a list of length `4`, where `A[0]` has length `222`, `A[1]` has length `261`, `A[2]` has length `212` and `A[3]` has length `201`. I want to create a new list of lists with same dimensions as `A` but with all entries initialised by 0s. How do I do this?

Code:

`A=[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12], [13,14]]`
I want to have `B` which should look like the following.
`B=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0]]`

What I tried was: `B= np.zeros_like(A)`
On printing `B` gives `B=[0 0 0 0]`

How do I fix this? Apologies if the terminologies are not consistent with the example.

Comment: `list` objects do not have a shape attribute....

Comment: By shape I mean, the value I get by using np.shape(A)

Comment: ... Right. So are you using numpy arrays? Or else why would you use `numpy.shape`???

Comment: `newA = [np.zeros_like(a) for a in A]`

Comment: Yes, I am using numpy arrays

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that this is a numpy question and add actual example code for the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @GergesDib if the OP were in fact using nested list objects, then there may be subtle ways this will not work as intended. Consider `(numpy.zeros_like([[1,2], [1]]))`

Comment: @GergesDib This doesn't seem to work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Any suggestions?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good catch. This works for list of lists where the inner lists are 1-D or a regular vector/matirx.

Comment: @Silvermoon My strongest suggestion is that you edit and clarify your question so that we can understand your problem better

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga GergesDib's proposal, in my opinion, is fine since OP did not provide enough information or clarity to say otherwise. Of course we can imagine all kind of wild things but do we have to?

Comment: It is impossible to help you without a [mcve] You claim to be working with a list of lists, but then you say you are working with numpy arrays. If you were working with a list of numpy arrays, then Gerges comment should have worked. But you claim it "doesn't work" but make no attempts to describe *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the question somewhat. Please see if it makes sense now, else I will add an example soon

Comment: With updated question, @GergesDib's solution should have worked. Something is wrong on your side.

Comment: To all: I am sorry to have asked this question with so less information. I am very new to programming and I am not very clear on the terminologies. I will try to be more clear in the future.

Comment: @GergesDib my main point was that `list` objects do not have properties like shape or dimension, and the OP needs to properly specify what they are working with, or else we can all sit around all day guessing

Comment: ... And therefore you need to provide some code so that we can try and figure things out for you, without you having to be very precise with terminology. The code will speak for itself.

Comment: @AGNGazer I am adding a code now.

Comment: @GergesDib Added a example code now

Comment: @AGNGazer Added an example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, you are NOT using `numpy`:

```
B = [len(a) * [0] for a in A]
```

@GergesDib's comment should have worked equally well:

```
B = [np.zeros_like(a) for a in A] # <-- @GergesDib
```

Also, here is a modified version of @GergesDib solution that gives you pure Python lists [which is what I suspect you wanted, but I am not sure]:

```
B = [np.zeros_like(a).tolist() for a in A]
```

Comment: Can you please suggest if I need to edit the terminologies in the question for better clarity for others

Comment: You are welcome, but @GergesDib example should have worked equally well.

Comment: Yes, your solution which you refer to as the one giving pure python lists gives the same solution. Can you please explain what is the difference between the two solutions?

Comment: @Silvermoon I am not sure how would I edit your question since, in my opinion, GergesDib solution should have worked for you. So, it is not clear why do you say it did not work for you and this confuses me. On one hand your text and code indicate that you are not using `numpy` and yet you are attempting to use it in your own solution and also use `np.shape()` to find the length of a Python list. It is simply confusing.

Comment: On a closer inspection, this is what GeorgesDib solution returns `B=[array[0,0,0,0], array[0,0,0], array[0,0,0,0,0], array[0,0]]`. I was not sure if it was the same since running that in Jupyter Notebook adds array to each list

Comment: @Silvermoon GergesDib original solution produces a *Python list* of 1D `numpy` arrays. The `tolist()` method of `numpy.ndarray` converts these arrays to pure Python lists and that is how I get a list of lists in the third solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with loops.

```
def gen_list(input_list):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        entry = ''
        for j in range(len(input_list[i])):
            entry += '0'
        output.append(entry)
    return output

foo = ['abc', '1234', 'acb123']

print(gen_list(foo))
```

This returns

```
['000', '0000', '000000']
```